localtime() always returns 23:59 despite of the actual time

Toolchain Version: 12.2.0+20230208
Host OS: Windows 11 64bit
platform and framework: esp32 dev module Platfromio | Arduino

Note: code works fine with toolchain version 8.4.0 but not with 12.2.0
Serial terminal output:
System time set to 04:20
Updated time (read using localtime()): 23:59

Sample code to recreate the issue:
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);

    // Set the desired time (4:20)
    struct tm localTime;
    localTime.tm_hour = 4;
    localTime.tm_min = 20;

    // Set the system time
    struct timeval newTime = { .tv_sec = mktime(&localTime), .tv_usec = 0 };
    if (settimeofday(&newTime, NULL) == 0) {
        printf("System time set to 04:20\n");

        // Read the updated time
        struct tm* updatedLocalTime = localtime(&newTime.tv_sec);
        printf("Updated time (read using localtime()): %02d:%02d\n", updatedLocalTime->tm_hour, updatedLocalTime->tm_min);
    } else {
        perror("Error setting system time");
    }
}


Can you provide [mcve]. Something I could copy paste and compile and run without any modification like adding missing code.

Are you using a C compiler or a C++ compiler?

You are complaining about localtime, but your code attempts to do settimeofday then it prints something. You should drop unimportant code and print problem immediately when it appears.

Does time return an error?

check the return value of mktime for -1.

Re "newTime.tv_sec = mktime(localTime);", Is this really allowed???

I updated my code to a more minimalistic version @MarekR

No time does not return any error @ikegami

what do u mean? mktime return type is time_t not an int! @stark

It's still an integer type. Docs say to check for (time_t)-1.

u were right! I checked it and it returns -1. @ikegami

It probably doesn't like that all the fields are zero and that you have a overly large seconds value. Try this: Get the time using time. Convert to local time using localtime, adjust the hours and minutes, convert to epoch time using mktime

It works fine when all members of localTime are initialized with valid values.

"t works fine when all members of localTime are initialized with valid values..." See dupe: What is the default value for C++ class members

You need to initialize localTime. Right now it has fields with indeterminate values which makes the program have undefined behavior since those are read by mktime. You could start by populating it with the current time and then change the members you'd like to change.
Example:
time_t now = time(NULL);
struct tm localTime = *localtime(&now); // initialize with current time
localTime.tm_hour = 4;
localTime.tm_min = 20;
localTime.tm_isdst = -1;

struct timeval newTime = { .tv_sec = mktime(&localTime), .tv_usec = 0 };


thanks for the answer I initialized it using your code but still having the same problem. the strange thing is that when I compile it using 8.4.0 version of esp32 toolchain it works fine and returns the actual time but with newer versions such as 12.2.0 the mktime returns -1

@MahyarShokraeian Ok, that's surprising. What happens if you don't change localTime at all after the initialization struct tm localTime = *localtime(&now); and then call mktime with it? Does that succeed?

I'm sorry I'll undo the changes. this code still returns -1: time_t now = time(NULL);     struct tm localTime = *localtime(&now);     printf("mktime value = %d", (int)mktime(&localTime));

@MahyarShokraeian In that case I don't have any explanation other than that your toolchain is broken I'm afraid :-(
